# Can't ctrl Z after setState() react

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a text in <input> have value "first" by using useState().

```
const [text, setText] = React.useState("");

const setStateOnClick = () => {
  setText("second");
};

const onchangeText = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  setText(value);
};

return (
  <div>
    <input value={text} onChange={(e) => onchangeText(e)} />
    <button onClick={setStateOnClick}>set new state</button>
  </div>
);
```

Begin, in <input> is: "first"

After I setText.

I can't "ctrl Z" to take back value("first") of begin text.

I try to catch the value by "onChange()" and put it in a stack, but it save every letters so performance will be decreased.

Is there a way to save the state of "ctrl Z" ? Thank you.

SOVLED.

```
export default function StateTextFields() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");
  const [textArr, setTextArr] = React.useState([]);
  const typingTimeoutRef = React.useRef(null);

  const setStateOnClick = () => {
    setText("second state");
  };
  const setStateUndo = () => {
    if (textArr.length > 0) {
      const NewArr = [...textArr];
      setText(NewArr[NewArr.length - 1]);
      NewArr.pop();
      setTextArr(NewArr);
    }
  };
  const onchangeText = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setText(value);
    if (typingTimeoutRef.current) {
      clearTimeout(typingTimeoutRef.current);
    }
    typingTimeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
      const NewArr = [...textArr];
      NewArr.push(value);
      setTextArr(NewArr);
    }, 300);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={text} onChange={(e) => onchangeText(e)} />
      <button onClick={setStateOnClick}>second</button>
      <button onClick={setStateUndo}>Undo</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Provided below is a working-example which shows that Ctrl+Z may be used to undo text typed in the input (unless the button is clicked).

**Code Snippet**

```js
const {useState} = React;
const Thingy = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const setStateOnClick = () => {
    setText("second");
  };

  const onchangeText = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setText(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={text} onChange={(e) => onchangeText(e)} />
      <br/>
      <br/>
      value in real-time: {text} <br/>
      Can use Ctrl+Z to undo entered text
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <button onClick={setStateOnClick}>set new state</button>
      <br />
      Cannot Ctrl+Z after above button is clicked !
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Thingy />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```html
<div id="rd" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

Based on updated question, a new button "Undo" has been added.

- The original text typed by the user is saved when user clicks the first button ("Confirm text").
- This info is also stored on an array `pastItems`.
- When there are entries in `pastItems` the `"Undo"` button is enabled and allows user to recall values one-by-one till no values remain.

```js
const {useState} = React;
const Thingy = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [pastItems, setPastItems] = useState([]);

  const setStateOnClick = () => {
    setPastItems(prev => ([...prev, text]));
    setText('');
    // setText(prev => (`${prev} - set to state`));
  };
  
  const undoOnClick = () => {
    const prevText = pastItems.pop();
    setPastItems([...pastItems]);
    setText(prevText);
  };

  const onchangeText = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setText(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label for="userInput">Type some text here: &emsp;</label>
      <input id="userInput" value={text} onChange={(e) => onchangeText(e)} />
      <br/>
      <br/>
      value in real-time: {text} <br/>
      prev values in real-time: {pastItems.join(', ')} <br/>
      Can use Ctrl+Z to undo entered text
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <button onClick={setStateOnClick}>Confirm text</button>
      &emsp; &emsp;
      <button onClick={undoOnClick} disabled={pastItems.length === 0}>Undo</button>
      <br /><br />
      Can "Undo" after 'Confirm' button is clicked !
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Thingy />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```html
<div id="rd" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to ctrl+Z after the button is clicked. I solved this by save the state every 300ms when user type in the input. Like the code above.